# Is the page served from cache or a request

Tags: javascript, performance

I am working with the performance.timings API in javascript to find the response time of a page load. But I do not need the value if it is served from the cache. Is there any way to detect if a request is served from the browsers cache?

Comment: "It is not javascript programmers task to do manage the cache, but the browser's."

Comment: Are you trying to test the performance of an ecosystem _from within that ecosystem_?

Comment: I am building something like newrelic where I am collecting data about response times from the browser. But I do not want data from pages served from the cache.